# What is the name of this formula: $1-(1-p)^n = x$?

Tags: probability

I asked this question yesterday regarding the probability of finding a code here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/267935/how-long-would-it-take-to-brute-force-an-otp

The answer I got seemed great and the formula provided was $1-(1-p)^n = x$

I was trying to find the name of this formula but it was not super clear when trying to Google it, since my background in math is not really up to date.

Comment: "the probability of *it* happening at least once in $n$ iid attempts"

Comment: Are you saying this formula doesn't really have its own name?

Comment: Most simple expressions have no special name attached to them.

Comment: The formula is the key for the first-success problem.

Comment: As an aside, I discourage you from trying to think just in terms of "formulas" and assuming that every individual result has its own name and has been written in exactly that way before.  Instead, you should learn the fundamentals and basics and use those as building blocks to get to what you want.

Comment: I think it is a special case of Survival function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a "named formula" but it follows from a few standard pieces of information.  First is "Law of Total Probability" or even more simply as [Complementary Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event) which implies that $\Pr(A)+\Pr(A^c)=1$.  Rearranged, that is $\Pr(A) = 1 - \Pr(A^c)$

The second basic piece might as well be described as [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which states that in $n$ independent trials wherein each trial has success chance of $p$... the probability of getting exactly $k$ successes will be $\Pr(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.  Applied to the case of $k=0$ that would give $\Pr(X=0)=(1-p)^n$

So, combining these we have $\Pr(X>0)=1-\Pr(X=0)=1-(1-p)^n$

---

In the linked question, the answerer gave the answer to the question "*How many trials are needed at a minimum to make it so that the probability of at least one success occurring is at least $0.5$?*"

That is, we are given $p$ and we want to find $n$ such that $\Pr(X>0)\geq 0.5$.

For this, use logarithms and some rearrangement of terms.  From $\Pr(X>0)=1-(1-p)^n\geq 0.5$ let us find where it is equal rather than having it as an inequality.  Rearrange to get $(1-p)^n=0.5$

From here, take the logarithm of both sides to have $\ln((1-p)^n)=\ln(0.5)$ and use properties of logarithms to have $n\ln(1-p)=\ln(0.5)$.  Divide and we have $n = \dfrac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(1-p)}$.  Using your specific value of $p$ gives [$n\approx 231049$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=log%280.5%29%2F%28log%281-3%2F1000000%29%29).

You could just as well have answered different questions such as "*How many trials are needed at a minimum so that we have a probability of at least $0.9$ to get at least one success?*" which is answered in the same way, here being $\dfrac{\ln(0.1)}{\ln(1-p)}$ which here evaluates to $\approx 767527$ and so on...

Comment: This is great! thanks for sharing all these details. By the way, I know this is a bit out of scope with this question but how do you actually use the formula? I was only provided with the answer in my other post and I'm not even sure how to get to that number with the formula

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette I don't understand your question.  "*How do you use the formula?*"  Are you asking how to interpret the superscript number?  Are you asking how to evaluate the result?  Are you asking what the formula describes?  Are you asking something else?

Comment: Here, $\Pr(X>0)=1-(1-p)^n$ describes the probability that we get at least one success within $n$ independent trials, each with success chance $p$.  As for the symbols used, the superscript is exponentiation which is one of the standard arithmetical operations alongside addition and multiplication.  As for getting a number out of it, the number $n$ is the number of trials and $p$ the probability of success on each individual attempt... perform the arithmetic and get the final result.  If the numbers are too messy, then plug it into a calculator.

Comment: I mean on my original post here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/267935/how-long-would-it-take-to-brute-force-an-otp - I was provided with `n≈231,049` but how do you get this number? What is the value of `x` supposed to be? Sorry, my background in math is really not that good!

Comment: I also tried to use online calculators but I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: You were given $p=\frac{3}{1000000}$.  The number $231049$ happened to be the smallest number $n$ such that $\Pr(X>0)\geq 0.5$.  To get the number $231049$ we can ask the question "what value of $n$ is such that $0.5 = 1 - (1-p)^n$."  Rearranging, that would be $(1-p)^n=0.5$.  Take the logarithm base $(1-p)$ of both sides.  That gives you $n\approx \dfrac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(1-\frac{3}{1000000})}\approx 231048.7$.  Round up since we have to have an integer number of trials.

Comment: Thank you so much! `x=0.5` - this is what I was missing. I managed to get the answer using the https://www.mathway.com/Algebra calculator! By the way I because this was out of scope I opened a new question (if you want to post your answer there): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4624914/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-this-formula-1%e2%88%921%e2%88%92%e2%81%bf